# How can I init ManyToMany field in django models that can't relate to itself(object level)?

Tags: python, django, orm, model

Example:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)

user = MyUser.object.get(pk=1)
user.blocked_users.add(user)
user.blocked_users.all()[0] == user # (!!!)
```

Can It be prevented on model/db level? Or we need just do check somewhere in app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Django docs for [`ManyToManyField` arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomany-arguments), it does not seem possible.

The closest argument to what you want is the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) However, that [**only limits choices** on ModelForms and admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) (you can still save it like you did in your example), and there is currently [no easy way to use it to limit based on another value (pk) in the current model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969081/3096768).

**If you want to prevent it from happening altogether**, you'll have to resort to [**overriding the save method on the through model**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799658/3096768)--something like:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField(..., through="BlockedUser")

class BlockedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    blocked = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Only allow this relationship to be created if 
        if self.user != self.blocked:
            super(BlockedUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You could of course also do this with [`signals`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals).

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I think override save method is what i need.